# Store Custom properties in aplicationContext.xml Spring file

Tags: spring, properties

I need to store some configuration parameters for a web application that uses spring framework.

Typically I'll use a configurationfile.properties file but i wonder if i can store that values in the applicationContext.xml file.

One workaround could be to create a JavaBean class to store the values, and build that class using spring, something like this:

```
<bean id="configurationBean" class="mypackage.someClass">
 <property name="confValue1">
   <value>myValue1</value>
 </property>
 ....
</bean>
```

But i would like to know if is there a way to store those parameters without the needing to create that class.

Thanks in advance.

---

I think that the best solution that fits my requirements is to use a java.util.Properties instance as a Spring Bean.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work with the following syntax.

```
<bean id="props" class="java.util.Properties" >
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="myKey">myValue</prop>
            <prop ...>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

You are taking advantage of the fact that java.util.Properties has a copy constructor that takes a Properties object.

I do this for a HashSet which also has a copy constructor (as do HashMaps and ArrayLists) and it works perfectly.

Comment: ApplicationContext app = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app.xml");
System.out.println(app.getBean("props")); the result is {}. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Spring has builtin support for specifying properties within the application context XML. See [section 3.3.2.4](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-collection-elements) of the Spring Reference docs.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

But i want to avoid to create one POJO object to store the properties. I Read the link you provided, i can specify properties but always inside a <bean> definition element, so that links the bean with a POJO class.

Comment: So you want the actual <bean> to be an instance of java.util.Properties?

Comment: That is what's i was searching for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll get the best results using Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which allows you to map values from a regular .properties file against properties defined on your beans.

http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer

The example shows how to set the JDBC connection properties directly on an instance of javax.sql.DataSource, eliminating the need for an intermediate "configuration bean."

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Your solution doesn't seem bad, but i would like not to create a separate .properties file but to store the properties values only in the appContext.xml file, and access them in Java code.

Comment: Then you want to refer to link Mark provided.  It shows how you can declare an instance of java.util.Properties in XML:

    <property name="adminEmails">
        <props>
            <prop key="administrator">administrator@example.org</prop>
            <prop key="support">support@example.org</prop>
            <prop key="development">development@example.org</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

Comment: @HyLian you can't just put arbitrary properties (that look like a .properties file) in an XML file.  You either have to follow the XML structure (as @brd6644 mentioned above) or put it in a separate .properties file, as he mentioned in his post.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:yourconfigurationfile.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

then

```
<bean id="configurationBean" class="mypackage.someClass">
    <property name="confValue1">
        <value>${myvalue1}</value>
    </property>
    ....
</bean>
```

and in yourconfigurationfile.properties

```
myvalue1= value1
```